# Function which converts from from a_func(A a_in) to b_func(B b_in) (c++)

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have a class of function (call it `AFunc`) which takes a parameter of type `A`, and a class of function (call it `BFunc`) which takes a parallel parameter of type `B` (i.e. there is a straightforward conversion from objects of type `A` to those of type `B`).

I need to write a function like the following:

```
using Afunc = AReturnType(*)(A);

using BFunc = BReturnType(*)(B);

BFunc convertFunction(AFunc a_func_in)
{
    BReturnType(*b_func_out) =
        [&](B b_in) {
            A a_in = A(b_in);
            AReturnType a_out = a_func_in(a_in);
            return BReturnType(a_out);
    };
    return b_func_out;
}
```

That is, a function which takes a function compatible with `A` types and returns a function compatible with `B` types.

My first thought was to define a function within the conversion function, but I quickly discovered that local functions are not supported in c++. My next thought was to use a lambda expression as above, but I have since learned that lambda functions can only be decayed to function pointers if they don't capture any references, however in this case the lambda needs to be aware of the `AFunc` parameter provided to the wider conversion function.

This is where I've run out of ideas. Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: Your explanation is hard to follow. Can you show an example with real, actual code that anyone can compile, or try to compile, and then explain, in detail, what exactly is your question.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo it seems, then, that I have found a small hole in the capabilities of c++. Thanks for your confirmation

Comment: My mistake. It seems I may have spoken too soon. I'm writing up an answer now. Not a full solution, but it may be helpful depending on your constraints. Hold tight

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that having a function pointer is stronger than simply having a callable object. The latter could be a function pointer, but it could also be a closure or a functor, both of which carry state. A function pointer is just that: a pointer to a function. No state, no special tricks. Just one chunk of code that can be executed on demand.

So, at least, there's no way to pass an `AFunc` at runtime and get a `BFunc`, the way you've defined everything, because that would involve generating new functions in the code itself at runtime, which C++ doesn't allow.

However, if you know the `AFunc` you want to apply this too at compile-time, we can use templates to get the same result. A template is evaluated at compile-time and actually generates code, so we can use it to come up with functions which have genuine function pointers. In fact, we're not even going to write a conversion function; we're just going to write our `BFunc` and then template parameterize it.

```
template <AFunc f>
BReturnType bFunc(B b) {
  return f(b);
}
```

Assuming the appropriate conversions exist, you can write something like `BFunc b = bFunc<sampleAFunc>;` and the compiler will generate the appropriate function (and corresponding pointer) for you.

Comment: [To be fair](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G19B7lTgwCE) you can actually do the runtime thing.  Make an array of (say) 1000 afunc pointers and 1000 bfunc pointers.  Populate then 1000 bfunc pointers with functions with a hard coded "lookup afunc number 7 in the array" etc.  Now when passed an afunc at runtime, stuff it into the 1000 rntry array and return the corresponding bfunc.  Throw on some hashing and reuse and recycling of bfunc pointers or whatever to taste.  This is, I might add, a horrible idea; but you can do it.